# how to write program that allows you to create directories in assembly language?

Tags: assembly

how to write program that allows you to create directories in assembly language?how to write program that allows you to create directories in assembly language?

Comment: What architecture and operating system are you programming for?

Answer (score 3):

You can write the program in assembly in the same way as you would write it in any other programming language: invoking a service of *Application Programming Interface* of the operating system which you want your program to run on.

For DOS it is [Int 21h/AH=39h MKDIR - CREATE SUBDIRECTORY](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2775.htm),

for MS Windows [CreateFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea),

for Linux [Functions for working with directories](https://profile.iiita.ac.in/bibhas.ghoshal/lab_files/System%20calls%20for%20files%20and%20directories%20in%20Linux.html)